# Microsoft Access Freezing during DoCmd.SendObject

Tags: ms-access

I built a Microsoft Access program/project/app/whatever that has the task of going out to users' own Access files on our shared drive and copying tables back to mine, doing some filtering then emailing the results. It worked but we just had some Microsoft Office upgrades and now it doesn't. I'm wondering if you can help. We went from IBM Note to Outlook. I'm pretty sure I had Access 2010 before but I had to go through a series of install screens when I opened it today.

There's obviously a lot more to it but the relevent chunk of code seems to be:

`Debug.Print emailBodyStr
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , selfrecordset.Fields.Item("emailTo"), , , selfrecordset.Fields.Item("emailTitle"), emailBodyStr, 0
    Debug.Print "email sent, clean up"`

The results I get back show the emailBodyStr content, I get a warning from Outlook that someone is trying to send an email on my behalf. I click allow, the email pops into my inbox then Access just sits there and I never see the clean up message featured above.

Any ideas why it's locking in my SendObject? Is there a better methodology for me to use to send an email with my the file path to my customers?

Comment: Don't know if it will make a difference, but the DoCmd line could be simpler. I've never seen or used the .Item property. DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , selfrecordset!emailTo, , , selfrecordset!emailTitle, emailBodyStr, 0

Comment: I'll certainly give it a try.

Comment: I just tested the .Item syntax and it does work, although .Item is not needed. Cannot replicate the issue. If you still have problem, post the entire procedure code.